# Configure tunnel between IPv6 enabled server and local IPv4 network

Tags: vpn, nat, ipv6, tunnel

I am newbie here and also for IPv6 network.
I have one debian installed server which is able to send IPv6 traffic.
Now in my local network, ISP not supporting IPv6 traffic. I want to configure tunnel or VPN or NAT 64 using my server to pass IPv6 traffic over IPv4 from my local IPv4 only network.

I am very eager to learn this out. Please help me if any solution for such configuration.

Comment: If your ISP doesn't have IPv6, where did you get your IPv6 addressing? There are IPv6 tunnel providers who will give you a free IPv6 tunnel and address block.

Comment: Hi @RonMaupin,
Sir thanks for your quick response. I am just confuse with that only. Tunnel providers providing Ipv6 addressing then why I can't create my IPv6 tunnel with IPv6 on my server.

As creating tunnel or VPN on IPv4, we get tunnel IP on 10.*.*.* series tunnel network So Is there any way to create such for IPv6 address in my scenario.

Whatever, I want to learn this so please pass any reference link so that I can do R&D on it.

Comment: IPv4 has run out of public IP addresses. IPv6 has plenty of IP addresses for the next century. Typically, you assign your IPv6 hosts global with IPv6 addresses, and you need to get those from somewhere. You can get global IPv6 addresses from your RIR, ISP, or a tunnel provider. IPv6 doesn't have NAT the way IPv4 does, because NAT was designed to conserve IPv4 addresses until IPv6 become ubiquitous. If you use ULA IPv6 addresses, you cannot connect to any global IPv6 hosts.

Comment: By the way, product or resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic here, so please don't ask for them.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible. Any VPN technology that can carry IPv6 over IPv4 will work. Personally I use openvpn as my go-to VPN solution but others may have other preferences.

The ideal configuration would be.

1. Your hosting provider allocates a block of IPv6 addresess for your VPN and routes it to your server.
2. You use that block to address systems on the VPN
3. Your server routes between the VPN and your hosting provider's network.
4. Machines on the VPN have their IPv6 default gateway pointed at the VPN.

Unfortunately this isn't possible with all hosting providers. Some providers will give you a block of addreses but they are "on-link" addresses for which traffic will only be delivered to your server if your server responds to neighbour-discovery requests for them. There is one provider i'm aware of who will only give your server a single v6 address.

So what are the alternatives?

One is NAT, the IPv6 proponents have a strong dislike for NAT but nevertheless Linux eventually implemented IPv6 NAT functionality, so you can use "unique-local" addresses on your VPN and use NAT to translate them to your server's global address.

The other is "proxy NDP". If your ISP allocated your server a block of "on-link" addresses you can set your server up to respond to neighour discover requests for those addresses without adding the addresses as local addresses on your server. You can then use the addresses to address systems on the VPN.

Comment: For this scenarios public IPv4 required on the server.

Answer (score 1):

If You don't have public IPv4 on the server and can't get IPv6 from ISP, then You can get IPv6 for Your LAN from IPv6 tunnel broker (search any working)